# confusion over definition of weight of a topological space

Tags: general-topology

I would like some clarifications over the definition for the weight of a topological space.  According to Engelking's General Topology text, 2nd edition, page 12, it states:

"Every set of cardinal numbers being well-ordered by $<,$ the set of all cardinal numbers of the form $|\mathcal{B}|,$ where $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for a topological space $(X,\mathcal{O}),$ has a smallest element; this cardinal number is called the ***weight of the topological space*** $(X,\mathcal{O})$ and is denoted by $\mathcal{w}((X,\mathcal{O})).$"

I am a bit confused over this definition.  The definition is defined in terms of a base of a topological space.  So when this cardinal number stating that a base $\mathcal{B}$ has a smallest element, is it referring to the smallest open set within a particular base for a topology, or is it referring to all possible bases which has the smallest number of open sets for a topology. Since for any given topology defined over an underlying set say $X$, there could be many different bases that could be defined for that particular topology.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you cite says the weight is the smallest cardinal from *all* bases, not of an open set for a given base. This removes any ambiguity. Concretely, given a space $(X,\tau)$ we could define

$$
\mathfrak{B} = \{B : \text{ $B$ is a basis for $X$}\}
$$

and then

$$
\omega(X,\tau) := \min_{B \in \mathfrak{B}} |B|.
$$

The justification for 'well definedness', as you cite, relies on the fact that these cardinals are well ordered.

**Edit:** as per the comments, here's a small example. If $X$ has a countable basis (for example, if $X$ is metrizable) then its weight is either finite or $\aleph_0$ (i.e. countable).

If additionally we ask for $X$ to be Hausdorff, then for each $x,y \in X$ we have $U_{x,y} \ni x$ and $V_{x,y} \ni y$ open and disjoint. Inductively given $x_1, \dots, x_n$ we can find a pariwise dijsoint collection $U_i \ni x_i$ of open sets. So if $X$ is infinite, then there are infinite basic open sets. Reciprocally, if $X$ is finite, then the amount of open sets (in particular basic ones) is bounded by $\mathcal{P}(X)$ which is finite.

This shows that

> **Proposition**. Let $(X,\tau)$ be a second countable Hausdorff space. Then$$\omega(X,\tau) = \min\{|X|,\aleph_0\}.$$

Comment: From what you have written, does it mean amongst all possible bases, the base that have the smallest cardinal would be the one that has the smallest number of open sets?

Comment: If by number of open sets of $B$ you mean the cardinal of $\{U : U \in B\}$ then yes, by definition this is the cardinal of $B$ (as the former set is exactly $B$). The number of 'total' open sets is always the same, since it is determined by the topology $\tau$ which is fixed.

Comment: So if we are given a topology and there could be more than one base defined for it and amongst all possible bases, they all have the same number of open sets.  Is that something that can be proved.  Because if they all have the same number of open sets, will defining different bases for the same topology would give what advantage?

Comment: It can be proved indeed: the number of open sets is the cardinal of $\{U \subset X : \text{ $U$ is open}\}$. This does not depend on any choice of basis. The convenience for defining different basis depends on the problem. For example, the euclidean $n$-space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a basis made up of open balls, and another one open rectangles (i.e. products of open intervals). The former is more intuitive from a 'metric' perspective (since it depends on the usual distance $d_2$) and the latter is more natural when thinking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a product space.

Comment: One last question, is the weight of a topological space easy to determine like the way people evaluate integrals in calculus.

Comment: To be honest, this is the first time I encounter this definition, so I can't make any bold claims. But in principle, the set of all basis of a space is **huge**, so it may not be very easy. However, there are certain [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) which tell us a space has a countable basis, and there this problem should be (I think) easier. It amounts to checking where a space has a finite amount of open sets.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the clarification.  I very much appreciated it.   :)

Comment: No problem! I'm writing up a small example to clarify my last comment.

Comment: Thank you for your additional comment.  It is reassuring after I saw what you posted.  :)